# Getting cURL error 6 trying to get DBs description using AWS SDK

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-rds

My environment:

```
OS: MacOS Big Sur Version 11.4
PHP: PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2021 17:21:21) ( NTS )
AWS SDK Version 3 (downloaded the latest today)
```

I am trying to run the following code:

```
<?php
include_once '../credentials/credentials.php';
require '../aws_sdk/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\Rds\RdsClient; 
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$rds = new Aws\Rds\RdsClient([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'us-east-1a2',
    'credentials' => ['key' => $aws_ccess_Key, 'secret' => $aws_secret_access_key]
]);

try {
    $result = $rds->describeDBInstances([]);
    var_dump($result);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo($ex->getMessage());
}
```

But, I am getting the following error message:

```
Error executing "DescribeDBInstances" on "https://rds.us-east-1a2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: rds.us-east-1a2.amazonaws.com (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Going to https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html does not offer much help:

```
CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST (6)

  Couldn't resolve host. The given remote host was not resolved.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in `'region'      => 'us-east-1a2',`? 
Should be `us-east-1a`.

Comment: Not really a typo, I coped that from the dashboard, but it appears this is not acceptable. The correct one is us-east-1. Is there a way to include all regions?

Comment: Not sure of the need to include all the regions when the RDS is in us-east-1? If the code is to be used for other regions/RDSs I believe it would be better if we make the region configurable i.e. take the value of `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` from environment variable? More info here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html